# Storing multiple entity orderings in a database

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a database, with one table containing a set of entities - let's say films. I want users on the front end to be able to create and save multiple orderings of these films.

How could I sensibly store these orderings? What should I be thinking about (for making the database schema nice, or for performance, etc.)?

---

In this particular case, I'm only expecting about 100 films in the database, and probably fewer than 10 saved orderings, so performance is unlikely to be a major issue, although in theory it could get much larger.

My ideas so far, without restricting for niceness, include;

1. Having a table for orderings, storing ordering id, ordering name,
   and a JSON.stringified version of the film ids.
2. Having a table storing ordering id and ordering name, and a separate
   table storing, somehow (a linked list?) several sets of actual
   orders - by storing as you might a single order but adding an order
   id. (This second table might then contain a record for every pair of
   film and order...)

Comment: By "orderings" do you mean "sorting"? Like their film preference, from 1-10? Or do you mean "order" like "purchase"?

Comment: Sorting. Sorry, I guess film was maybe a misleading example there (although I'd hope context in the rest of the question would give enough).

Answer (score 0):

Your ideas basically cover it, omitting some implementation-specific options such as Postgres' array field support which is for practical purposes a different way to accomplish #1.

#1 is compact and easy to set up, but lacks referential integrity: if you delete a film, you have to ensure it is removed from all lists yourself. #2 involves more work and a slightly more complex structure, but the payoff is that the relationships are tracked by the database; taking the example of deleting a film, you have the option to prevent deletion of any film on a list, or of cascading the deletion to remove the entry from all lists.

Each has its advantages and disadvantages. Which is appropriate really comes down to your specific use case.